# Accessing the callback functions arguments

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
function wrapper(fn) {
 
  return function(...args) {
    console.log(args);
   fn.apply(this, args);
    return this;
  }
}


function Person() {}

Person.prototype.setName = wrapper(function (first, last) {
  this.first = first;
  this.last = last;
})

Person.prototype.sayName = function () {
  console.log(this.first + ' ' + this.last);
}


const p = new Person();
p.setName('John','Doe');
p.sayName();
```

in the sample code pattern, the console statement prints the arguments passed to the "wrapper" function (which is ["john", "doe"]).
My confusion is how it can read the callback functions arguments in the returned function. Appreciate any pointer to help in understanding this.

Answer (score 0):

This seems unnecessarily confusing piece of code, you could achieve the same result with much less code. That being said, it is because with ***apply*** you call a function (your callback function) with a given this value (which you already have) and arguments, which is an array in this case with the values of "John" and  "Doe".
You can read more about apply [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Comment: i know this is a contrived example to create this scenario. Probably i am not super clear in explain it; my question was how "args" which is an inner function gets the callback function's argument.

Comment: @lavender You get the args because when you call setName, you call wrapper and you pass function (fn), then this function applies its arguments to the inner function (this will point to the inner function and args now will be accessible by the inner function aswell). If you do not know what **apply** is and how it works, it will be difficult for you to understand, also you must know how **this** works and behaves.